# How to add secondary label to UITableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to know how to add the secondary `UILabel` to an `UITableViewCell`, by secondary label I mean a grey label at the right side of the cell, I've tried:

```
`cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "TEST"`
```

But this text doesn't show up, I want something like this:

[image: I want something like this]

Comment: This is more than likely a subclass of `UITableViewCell` with a corresponding `xib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a `UITableViewCell` with appropriate style to have the `detailTextLabel` available, for example:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "SOME_CELL_IDENTIFIER")
```

Using xib you can do this from Attributes Inspector, set `Style` to be `Right Detail`:

Now if you try your code it should work:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "TEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically, you would go into your custom cell file, and create a detail label and and anchor it in awakeFromNib

```
let detailsLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.text = "TEST"
    return label
}()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    addSubView(detailsLabel)

    detailsLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    detailsLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    // Initialization code
}
```